# In Laravel 5.4 I need to check a checkbox if it was checked on a previous save

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I cant for the life of me work out what I need to do to get my checkbox to display checked if I previously checked it on my one database entry.

My database has a field called languages. In it I store the languages that users are fluent in. I do this with them filling out a form that includes a lot of checkboxes. This is what my form looks like:

```
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox" name="languages[]" value="English"> English
                            </label><br/>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox" name="languages[]" value="Finnish"> Finnish
                            </label><br/>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox" name="languages[]" value="French"> French
                            </label><br/>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox" name="languages[]" value="German"> German
                            </label><br/>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox" name="languages[]" value="Italian"> Italian
                            </label><br/>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox" name="languages[]" value="Portugese"> Portugese
                            </label><br/>
```

Then when I save it to the database, it saves like this:

```
["English", "Portugese"]
```

I have made an edit page, but how do I mark for example, English and Portguese as checked when I open the edit form?

The MySQL table column is a JSON column. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the [Laravel Collective Form library](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) is really useful for managing state in form elements.

```
$selected = ['English', 'Portuguese'];

{!! Form::checkbox('languages[]', 'English', in_array('English', $selected)) !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('languages[]', 'Finnish', in_array('Finnish', $selected)) !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('languages[]', 'French', in_array('French', $selected)) !!}
...
```

To answer your follow up question, to use a `select` field, you'd do the following:

```
$options = [
    // 'Value' => 'Label'
    'English' => 'English',
    'Finnish' => 'Finnish',
    'French'  => 'French',
];
$selected = 'English';

{!! Form::select('language', $options, $selected) !!}
```

Comment: This actually worked really well! Might I ask, I was reading the link you gave and dropdowns are very confusing there. If I had to use a dropdown in some areas, how would that work compared to the above for selecting the correct items?

Comment: Will the dropdown be single or multi-select?

Comment: it would be single

Comment: I've added an example. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Ahh that is amazing! Thanks so much! I just tested it and it works really well!